# Nested Loop Pattern, Java

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I need to make my output like the expected output. I tried to add the symbol | , but the output is not like the expected output

**my output:**

```
+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+
+-+-+-+
```

**expected output:**

```
+-+-+-+
| | | |
+-+-+-+
| | | |
+-+-+-+
| | | |
+-+-+-+
```

**This is my code:**

```
   package practice3;
    public class onBoard {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
                   for (int row = 0; row <= 3; row++)
                   { 
                       for (int col = 1; col <= 3; col++)
                       {
                           System.out.print("+-");                
                       }  
                       
                       System.out.println("+");
                   }
               }
        }
```

Comment: So print some lines with `| ` in them.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow :) You said that you tried to add | but this printing is not visible at all in your code, what did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```java
for (int row = 0; row <= 4; row++)
{
    if(row % 2 == 0) // If row is an even number print +-+
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= 3; col++)
        {
            System.out.print("+-");
        }
        System.out.println("+");

    }
    else // If odd number print | | | ...
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= 3; col++)
        {
            System.out.print("| ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
}
```

Welcome to SO! Next time you ask something I suggest you start doing something yourself and then asking, this way you grow and learn.

Comment: Of course it answers the question, but I don't see the point of answering the homework of a student directly without letting him explain what he exactly tried and where he's stuck. The question of imnfrhn doesn't even show the character "|" so I think he could have try harder before receiving the response :)